# Не работает Python turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle

Код:

```
import turtle
#import turtle as t
turtle.bgcolor("black")
turtle.tracer(50)
turtle.pensize(7)
turtle.goto(-40,-300)
c = ['red', 'yellow']
turtle.rt(4)
for i in range(300):
    turtle.color(c[i%2])
    turtle.up()
    turtle.circle(300-i, -92)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.circle(300-i, -92)
turtle.done()
```

В терминале:

```
PS C:\Users\atv\Desktop\Python 2.0> & C:/Users/atv/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe "c:/Users/atv/Desktop/Python 2.0/turtle.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\atv\Desktop\Python 2.0\turtle.py", line 1, in <module> 
    import turtle
  File "c:\Users\atv\Desktop\Python 2.0\turtle.py", line 3, in <module> 
    t.bgcolor("black")
    ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'turtle' has no attribute 'bgcolor' (most likely due to a circular import)
PS C:\Users\atv\Desktop\Python 2.0>
```

ссылка на видео с кодом:
https://youtu.be/C7rD6jDgbrE

Comment: Переименуйте свой файл

Comment: Спасибо сработало!

Answer (score 2):

Так как файл назван `turtle.py`, то Python думает, что Ваш файл - это и есть модуль Turtle. Поэтому он пытается импортировать сам себя, а в нем, естессна, нет функции `bgcolor`. Переименуйте свой файл, например, в `turtle1.py`.